# Is the character Etna from Disgaea based on an obscure Manga?

Tags: disgaea

The following picture is from a chapter of the magazine released in October of 2002. It's the title page and I've added a picture of the castle the story takes place in from a later page.

[image]

Supposedly *Disgaea* is from 2003-01-30, otherwise I'd have suspected the manga to be a parody. And for comparison, a picture of the castle in Disgaea and Etna:

[image]

Comment: **NSFW warning**: the referred manga is from an adult manga/hentai magazine.

Comment: If I might ask,  from which magazine did you find the manga?

Comment: The magazine is called Comic LO.

Comment: @AkiTanaka Can we say the NSFW at the start please?